# Change custromer-request-type in Jira ServiceDesk via REST API

Tags: jira-rest-api

I can receive the values of an created ticket using the SD API like:
GET /servicedeskapi/request/SD-4532
and within that i find something like:

```
{
    "issueId": "71928",
    "issueKey": "SD-4532",
    "requestTypeId": "121",
    "serviceDeskId": "5",
    ...
}
```

whereas "requestTypeId" related to the type created by the user (e.g. has a label "Common question").
Now i want to change the request type to, let's say "Hardware issue" which have the requestTypeId of "89".

When i try to change by POST /servicedeskapi/request/SD-4532
and giving a payload of

```
{
    "requestTypeId": "89",
}
```

I get a "405 - Method not allowed". Also the Jira ServiceDesk REST-API doc does not state anything about a POST method for this.

So i tried the common Jira REST-API
PUT /api/2/issue/SD-4532
and give payload

```
{
    "fields": {
        "customfield_10001": {
            "requestType": {
                "id": "89"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that give me an "Field 'customfield_10001' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown." error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the Jira ServiceDesk REST API docs do not state anything about a POST method for this because.... there is no POST method for this. You cannot change a request (issue) type simply by altering the value of the field that contains the ID (metadata) of that request type.

Do a Google search on *"jira rest api change issue type"* to see the many other times this question has been discussed in the past in many places. In a nutshell, changing types is not possible via the REST API, only the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jira Rest API to update Jira issue information. https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-put

// This code sample uses the 'node-fetch' library:
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const bodyData = `{
  "fields": {
    "customfield_10010": "ABC-09",
    "customfield_10000": {
      "air": "",
      "type": "doc",
      "name": "Sample Process",
      "avatarUrl": null
    }
  }
}`;

fetch('https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(
      'email@example.com:<api_token>'
    ).toString('base64')}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: bodyData
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(
      `Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
    );
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

> email@example.com --> Your Jira emailid
> <api_token> --> This is from your account token generated

Note:- Before using any API check if it's not experimental as this may cause issues in future due to sudden change in req/resp from Jira.

Try to inspect Jira dashboard network tab to understand more.